# Get Maximum Amount Multiple of 50, without cents

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, floating-point

I'm trying to fill a textbox with an amount that can be divided by 50 and with no cents.

Examples:
Amount -> 52353.85
Should Display -> 52350

Amount-> 1229.68
Should Display-> 1200

How can I modify the value?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems rounding can be arbitrary?

Comment: rounding seems to make sense. Round it off to the nearest whole number that is divisible by 50

Comment: actually, sorry it doesn't make sense. 1229.68 should round up to 1250. Do you want it to always round down to nearest 50?

Comment: @Greg we could add 25 to the old value if we want the number could round up. please see my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int newValue = (int)(oldValue / 50) * 50;
```

add 25 to the old value if you want the number could round up

```
int newValue = (int)((oldValue + 25) / 50) * 50;
```

Answer (score 2):

This gives the properly rounded result:

```
return Math.Round(x / 50.0) * 50;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return (int)x - ((int)x % 50);
```